# How to restore the trained result after stopping training model in Python?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a problem with training neural networks is in the choice of the number of training epochs to use. Too many epochs can lead to long time and overload CPU, sometimes halt the CPU. And I don't want to train the dataset from the beginning.

Is there anyway to **store** the a**lready-trained** information to the harddisk and **re-store** the **trained result**?

Answer (score 0):

There are many options, you may consider using [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). From my personal experience, it is very fast and efficient.

If you have a trained `model`, you can simply do this to save it to the HDD:

```py
import pickle

pickle_out = open("model.pickle", "wb")
pickle.dump(model, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

The model will be saved under the name `model.pickle`.

To retrieve the model from your code:

```py
pickle_in = open("model.pickle", "rb")
model = pickle.load(pickle_in)
```

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion. I'll try with this.